# Query to get the difference from a column

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have two tables with primary key "poll_id" and columns in each named "object_id".
I can't manage get the objects from t1 that don't exist in t2 and are with poll_id (primary key) something.

```
       T1                           T2

poll_id|object_id            poll_id|object_id
1      | 2                    1     |  2
1      | 3                          |
```

I need to get `[poll_id]=>1,[object_id]=>3`

Comment: "I can't manage get only the objects from t1 that don't exist in t1": wha??

Comment: Why don't you show us your current query?

Comment: LOL that's a quantum query. Haven't you heard em

Comment: And the `PRIMARY KEY` of table `T1` cannot be `poll_id`. Not with this data.

Comment: my bad - `PRIMARY KEY` is (poll_id, object_id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using **NOT EXISTS**

```
SELECT poll_id, object_id
FROM t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM t2
        WHERE t2.poll_id = t1.poll_id
          AND t2.object_id = t1.object_id
      ) 
  AND poll_id = 1 ;                        -- additional requirement
```

using **LEFT JOIN / IS NULL**

```
SELECT t1.poll_id, t1.object_id
FROM t1
  LEFT JOIN t2
    ON  t2.poll_id = t1.poll_id
    AND t2.object_id = t1.object_id
WHERE t2.object_id IS NULL 
  AND t1.poll_id = 1 ;                        -- additional requirement
```

using **NOT IN**:

```
SELECT poll_id, object_id
FROM t1
WHERE (poll_id, object_id) NOT IN
      ( SELECT poll_id, object_id
        FROM t2
      ) 
  AND poll_id = 1 ;                        -- additional requirement
```

Comment: I need to add specify a poll_id

Answer (score 2):

try

```
select t1.* from t1 
left join t2 on t1.poll_id = t2.poll_id and t1.object_id = t2.object_id
where t2.object_id is null
```

Comment: add a `where poll_id = 123` for instance to the end of your query